# Using import range to connect 30 spreadsheets into master Google sheet. How can I allow access all at once?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am working on a master spreadsheet which my manager/coworkers will use. Each manager/coworker will add [30 individual survey spreadsheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLVKi.png) into a master sheet. Another tab named "results here" utilizes [import range for all 30 sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Awehf.png). Is there a way my manager/coworkers can just "Allow access" once instead of needing to click "Allow access" 30 times. Or is there a better method of aggregating data from 30 individual spreadsheets into a master sheet without needing to hit "Allow access" numerous of times. Thanks!

Comment: there's no way to bypass it. each sheet needs to be connected separately one by one allowing the access

Comment: Yes, use auto hot key or some other macro software to click the button for you.

Comment: Unable to do so since my managers/colleagues are not technical. Please note it's 1 mastersheet per manager/colleague. So essentially each person has to allow access 30x.

Comment: @kay then you create the script in a way where it is just the hit of a button, is the issue that each person owns their own spreadsheet so they each need to importrange because you don’t have read access to their original sheet? I don’t understand why each person has to allow access.

Comment: @Kay If feasible, create the survey with [Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/forms) and distribute the link to employees. much faster to aggregate responses in one sheet.